# "list index out of range" Error (Python3)

Tags: python, function

My Code :

```
from random import randint
import os
path = os.path.abspath('')

dosya = open((path + "\\asaldb.txt"), "r")
asalsayilar = dosya.readlines()
mindeger = int(input("minumum Değer Kaç ? "))
maxdeger = int(input("Maximum Değer Kaç ? "))
min=0
max=0

def minasal():
    global min
    if int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger:
        print("Min : ")
        print(asalsayilar[min])
        min=min+1
        minasal()
    if not int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger :
        min=min+1
        minasal()
minasal()

def maxasal():
    global max
    if maxdeger>=int(asalsayilar[max]):
        print("Max : ")
        print(asalsayilar[max])
        max=max+1
        maxasal()
maxasal()
```

TreeBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asal.py", line 25, in <module>
    minasal()
  File "asal.py", line 21, in minasal
    minasal()
  File "asal.py", line 21, in minasal
    minasal()
  File "asal.py", line 21, in minasal
    minasal()
  [Previous line repeated 21 more times]
  File "asal.py", line 18, in minasal
    minasal()
  File "asal.py", line 18, in minasal
    minasal()
  File "asal.py", line 18, in minasal
    minasal()
  [Previous line repeated 66 more times]
  File "asal.py", line 14, in minasal
    if int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I only run maxasal() or just minasal yi work. but they do not work together.
How can I create a list with two elements and a common element? (maxasal() and minasal() )
Why do I get this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: I don't see `while int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger:` anywhere in your code. The error seems to be from a different script.

Comment: `minasal()` increments `min` before each time it recurses. When `min` gets to the number of lines in the file, you'll get an error.

Comment: Sorry . Incorrect Scripting. I fixed it.

Comment: Can you describe what these functions are supposed to do? And/or use English variable names?

Comment: The prime numbers in asaldb.txt should be lower and higher than the number in the input.

Comment: It's generally unpythonic to use recursion when in place of looping. Python has a limited stack size.

Comment: `if int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger:` and `if not int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger :` look suspicious to me. It is a common antipattern among new users to have two conditionals with opposite predicates, with the expectation that only one of them will run at a time. But it's possible that one will run right after the other, since your `min` value changes during the function. What happens if you replace `if not int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger :` with `else:`?

Comment: The use of global variables is also suspicious. Maybe you should pass `min` and `max` as function arguments.

Comment: `min` and `max` are inbuilt functions. You should not use them as variable names

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: I understand the problem. We need to apply 66 operations on the minass () operation. but after the list is over, he's trying to apply it at 67. how can i solve it?

Comment: `minasal` should always blow up because you have no way to stop recursion. Isn't this just a normal error for when user inputs a bad "minumum Değer Kaç ? " ? You could catch the exception and have the use try again.